# How to get the input type submit ID and apply javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using below jsp' form to submit the data. Before submitting I want to apply javascript.

```
<form name="inventory" method="post" action="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Tdata_Main" class="form-light mt-20" role="form" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
```

Now, I have three input tags of 'Submit' type

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-two" value="Update Inventory">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-two" value="Add Empty Row">               
<input type="submit" id="submitDelete" name="submit" class="btn btn-two" value="Delete Row">
```

After adding three new columns and filling in the data one by one, I added forth one as shown below. Now, I am in no need of this forth empty row hence I want to delete it. But the javascript code is getting applied here too and asking me to fill in the blank fields.

[image]

Below is the javascript code that is getting executed on the onSubmit event initiated from form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validate(form) {   
        //alert(form.id);
        if(form.id != "submitDelete"){  // NOT WORKING
            for(var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++){
                if(form.elements[i].type == "text"){
                    if(form.elements[i].value.length == 0 || form.elements[i].value.length == "null"){
                        alert('No value entered in '+form.elements[i].name+'.');
                        form.elements[i].focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }   
        if (confirm("Would you like to proceed!") == true) {
            return true;
        } 
        else{                   
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

How could I avoid getting this javascript code being applied on **Delete** using Javascript. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Only one thing you should remove the action attribute from your form element and post that data using javascript only.

Also your delete button is disabled. Enable it and it will work fine

Comment: _Why_ to remove attribute ? Where it is disabled ?

Comment: @Rayon I edited that later, it was disabled before :)

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for quick reply. Could you please let me know where to add that code and what code should be actually added.?

Comment: You can follow this link for a quick solution on how to post data using javascript http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/getelementbyid-form.phtml